# How to convert time format in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I tried convert 2018-08-22 11:13:00 (datetime64[ns]) to only 20180822 (object).

I have this code:

```
df_ICF_news['date'] = df_ICF_news['date'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(str(x), format='%Y%m%d'))
```

but don`t work:

```
ValueError: time data '2022-10-28 11:09:00' does not match format '%Y%m%d' (match)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `to_datetime` directly on the Series and don't provide a format, then use `dt.strftime` with your output format:

```
df_ICF_news['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_ICF_news['date']).dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering that the dataframe is `df_ICF_news` and that the column `date` is of `datetime64[ns]`, one option would be to use a list comprehension with [`pandas.Series.dt.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) as follows

```
df_ICF_news["date"] = [x.strftime("%Y%m%d") for x in df_ICF_news["date"]]

[Out]:

       date
0  20180822
date    object
dtype: object
```

If OP wants to use [`pandas.Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html), one can do the following

```
df_ICF_news["date"] = df_ICF_news["date"].apply(lambda x: x.strftime("%Y%m%d"))
```

---

**Notes:**

- There are strong opinions on using `.apply()`, so one might want to read this: [When should I (not) want to use pandas apply() in my code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54432583/7109869)